# Four Arranged Figures are offset

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, minipage

How can I ensure that the four plots (which are all the same size pdfs) appear with the same spacing:  see they are offset here:

[image: Offset Image]
   % Actual versus predicted plots

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/immediate_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/immediate_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/immediate_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\hspace{0.1cm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/immediate_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Actual Versus Predicted Plots}\label{multiavp}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try with removing the empty lines in between. They are starting a new line. For the captions see the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package. That would also fix the minipage problem completely.

Comment: Awesome @percusse, you've helped me out again.  Is there a good way   to only reference the entire figure with a single caption/label?

Comment: Yes subcaption package has a `\phantomcaption` command which will hide the individual one to which it is provided but leaves the main caption untouched.

Comment: Great, all set on the captions -- any chance you could shed some light on the offset nature of the plots?

Comment: @mike Try a run with all four images being the same .pdf or with `[demo]{graphicx}`, problem is your second image is not the same size.

Comment: I've tried with all 4 being the same .pdf, and the second one is still offset -- what can I adjust to fix this?

Comment: I would try `\hfill` between the first two and the second two figures and adding a manual linebreak. Having three `\hspace`s is weird. I'm not saying it's to blame but it can't help.

Comment: \hfill makes them both off-set.  Removing all of the \hspaces also doesn't work -- what am I missing here?  I've updated the code and image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken your code and made a few modifications, such as removing all `\centering` statements: They're not needed if you (i) use `\hspace{\fill}` directives between the first and second and between the third and fourth `minipage`s and (ii) set the width of the graphs inside each `minipage` to `\linewidth`. Incidentally, I would use the `\textwidth` parameter to specify the width of `minipage` environments, and `\linewidth` (or a fraction thereof) for measurements *inside* a `minipage` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % leave off demo option in real program
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/immediate_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\caption{Actual Versus Predicted: Immediate}
\label{fig:immediate}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/proximal_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\caption{Actual Versus Predicted: Proximal}
\label{fig:proximal}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{0.5cm} % (or whatever vertical separation you prefer)
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/distal_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\caption{Actual Versus Predicted: Distal}
\label{fig:distal}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/combined_formula_s_avp.pdf}
\caption{Actual Versus Predicted: Combined}
\label{fig:combined}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, I really like your solution, its extremely elegant but I was just wondering if I can modify this for a two column document format ?

Comment: @CutestPenguin - Have you tried replacing the `figure` environment with a `figure*` environment?